# Samsung Galaxy S4 turns off internet at night

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4

On my friends S4 the internet connections (WiFi etc.) turn off automatically from 10pm and turns on again at 6am the following morning, so he gets no messages between those times.

Is there a way we can change it maybe?

Comment: Galaxy S4 has 'Blocking Mode' to turn off connections at specific times, you can set exceptions so allow calls from a few people or Gmail only notifications etc. This should do it.

Answer (score 1):

Try the profile settings. He probably has set a "night"-profile which turns down the volume and activates the plane-mode. The profile settings can be found in the normal settings of your phone.

Answer (score 0):

In your notification shader, look for the "Blocking mode" icon, tap and hold it. You can activate the blocking mode there, pick a time frame for when it is active (e. g. 10pm - 8 am) and select what should be disabled from incoming calls, notifications, alarms and the LED indicator.

You can also allow only calls from certain contacts to go through to you, which can be helpful for emergency situations.